# Outlook HTML signature using VML - sends as converted image

Tags: outlook, vml

Whilst trying to get a background-image working in a  in Outlook, I tried using VML which works great:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:540px;height:196px;">
<v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.website.com/background-image.jpg" color="#888888" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
<div>

<p>my signature content</p>

</div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
 </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

However, when sending this signature from Outlook to a mac, the VML area and the HTML content inside it appear to be converted to a image?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it here: 
http://grabalife.com/2011/05/19/using-mailchimp-and-background-images-in-your-table-cells/

(not wrapping your HTML content in VML)